# ML model class in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I wrote a simple binary classification model with logistic regression. I would like to rearrange it into classes, with the help of inheritance. The output I get is not what I wanted: the script does not return the requested plots and results. The results is something like this:

<bound method PreProcessing.show_datafile of <**main**.PreProcessing object at 0x000001B0DCB89AC0>>
<bound method PreProcessing.general_info of <**main**.PreProcessing object at 0x000001B0DCB89AC0>>
count   mean    std   min   25%    50%    75%    max
Outcome                   768.0    0.3    0.5   0.0   0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
DiabetesPedigreeFunction  768.0    0.5    0.3   0.1   0.2    0.4    0.6    2.4
Pregnancies               768.0    3.8    3.4   0.0   1.0    3.0    6.0   17.0
SkinThickness             768.0   20.5   16.0   0.0   0.0   23.0   32.0   99.0
BMI                       768.0   32.0    7.9   0.0  27.3   32.0   36.6   67.1
Age                       768.0   33.2   11.8  21.0  24.0   29.0   41.0   81.0
BloodPressure             768.0   69.1   19.4   0.0  62.0   72.0   80.0  122.0
Insulin                   768.0   79.8  115.2   0.0   0.0   30.5  127.2  846.0
Glucose                   768.0  120.9   32.0   0.0  99.0  117.0  140.2  199.0
<bound method PreProcessing.target_distribution of <**main**.PreProcessing object at 0x000001B0DCB89AC0>>
<bound method PreProcessing.variables_distribution of <**main**.PreProcessing object at 0x000001B0DCB89AC0>>
<bound method PreProcessing.correlation of <**main**.PreProcessing object at 0x000001B0DCB89AC0>>
<bound method PreProcessing.scaler of <**main**.PreProcessing object at 0x000001B0DCB89AC0>>
<**main**.Logit object at 0x000001B0DCB89100>

Would anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

```
datafile = pd.read_csv(r'diabetes_dataset.csv')  
label = datafile['Outcome']  #
cols = list(datafile.columns[:-1])   
variable_name = 'Outcome'  
main_dir = 'Final_folder'  
output_folder = os.path.join(main_dir, 'output')

scaled_dataset = pd.read_csv('scaled_dataset.csv')
new_variable_name = 'Label'




class Model:

    def __init__(self, scaled_dataset, label, new_variable_name):
        self.df = scaled_dataset
        self.label = label
        self.new_variable_name = new_variable_name

        self.model_name = self.LR_model()


    def split(self):
        y = self.label.values
        X = self.df.drop(labels=self.new_variable_name, axis=1).values
        X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, random_state=42)  
        print("N. training cases:", y_train.shape[0], "- N. test cases:", y_val.shape[0])

    @property
    def fitting(self):
        return self.model_name.fit(X_train, y_train)

    def train_predict(self):
        predicted = self.model_name.predict(X_train)
        print("Classification report for Training set classifier \n %s:\n\n%s\n"
              % (self.model_name, metrics.classification_report(y_train, predicted)))
        print("AUC train set:\n%s" % metrics.roc_auc_score(y_train,
               self.model_name.predict_proba(X_train)[:, 1]))

        class_names = [0, 1]
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(class_names))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, class_names)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, class_names)
        sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_train, predicted)), annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu", fmt='g')
        ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.title('Confusion matrix train set', y=1.1)
        plt.ylabel('Actual label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

    def val_predict(self):
        predicted_val = self.model_name.predict(X_val)
        print("\nClassification report for Validation set classifier \n %s:\n\n%s\n"
              % (self.model_name, metrics.classification_report(y_val, predicted_val)))
        print("AUC validation set:\n%s" % metrics.roc_auc_score(y_val, self.model_name.predict_proba(X_val)[:, 1]))

        # Confusion Matrix:
        print("\n")
        class_names = [0, 1]
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(class_names))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, class_names)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, class_names)
        sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_val, predicted_val)), annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu", fmt='g')
        ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.title('Confusion matrix validation set', y=1.1)
        plt.ylabel('Actual label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

    def val_roc_curve(self):
        prob_test = self.model_name.predict_proba(X_val)
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_val, prob_test[:, 1])
        plot_roc_curve(self.model_name, X_val, y_val)
        plt.show()

    def LR_model(self):
        pass


class Logit(Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.classifier = LogisticRegression()
        self.parameters = {'C': [1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10],
                           'penalty': ['l1', 'l2', 'elasticnet', 'none'],
                           'solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga']}

    @property
    def LR_model(self):
        CV_modelLR = GridSearchCV(estimator=self.classifier,
                                  param_grid=self.parameters,
                                  cv=3, verbose=2)
        CV_modelLR.fit(X_train, y_train)
        best_params = CV_modelLR.best_params_
        logit = LogisticRegression(penalty=best_params['penalty'],
                                   C=best_params['C'],
                                   solver=best_params['solver'],
                                   class_weight='balanced')
        return logit

    def best_train_predict(self, logit):
        predicted = logit.predict(X_train)
        print("Classification report for Training set classifier \n %s:\n\n%s\n"
              % (logit, metrics.classification_report(y_train, predicted)))
        print("AUC train set:\n%s" % metrics.roc_auc_score(y_train, logit.predict_proba(X_train)[:, 1]))

        class_names = [0, 1]
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(class_names))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, class_names)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, class_names)
        sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_train, predicted)), annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu", fmt='g')
        ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.title('Confusion matrix train set', y=1.1)
        plt.ylabel('Actual label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

    def best_val_predict(self, logit):
        predicted_val = logit.predict(X_val)
        print("\nClassification report for Validation set classifier \n %s:\n\n%s\n"
              % (logit, metrics.classification_report(y_val, predicted_val)))
        print("AUC validation set:\n%s" % metrics.roc_auc_score(y_val, logit.predict_proba(X_val)[:, 1]))

        # Confusion Matrix:
        print("\n")
        class_names = [0, 1]
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(class_names))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, class_names)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, class_names)
        sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_val, predicted_val)), annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu", fmt='g')
        ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.title('Confusion matrix validation set', y=1.1)
        plt.ylabel('Actual label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

    def best_val_roc_curve(self, logit):
        prob_test = logit.predict_proba(X_val)
        _, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_val, prob_test[:, 1])
        plot_roc_curve(logit, X_val, y_val)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = Logit()
    print(model)
```

Comment: If your issue is the way the print statement is appearing and not the actual results, you probably just need to define the `__str__` method in your `Model` class to override the built-in method.

Comment: This is a good resource: https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__repr__/ . TL;DR: by default, `__str__` references `__repr__`, which references the object's location in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just add **str** dunder method to your class or parent class. In ret you define what you want to see after typing `print(object)`. Of course, it don't have to be `ret`, you can do it in a return statement like `return f"Object value: {self.value}`"

```
def __str__(self):
    ret = 'String or any value from object'
    return ret
```